# python 2.7 urlencode или quote: работа с юникодом

Tags: python, unicode

Здравствуйте.

Я работаю в GAE и мне необходимо передать в GET-запросе переменную с юникодом:

http://somesite.com/?message=Hello%20world

Функция из urllib выдает следующее:
    >>> urllib.quote(u'апб')

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1250
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    urllib.quote(u'апб')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 1250, in quote
    return ''.join(map(quoter, s))
KeyError: u'\xe0'
```

Как заставить питон преобразовать юникод в закодированную строку?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`KeyError: u'\xe0'` — это [проблема кодировок в интерактивной консоли](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421145/python-unicode-strings-and-the-python-interactive-interpreter), которая неправильно думает о кодировке вводимого:

```
>>> u'апб'
u'\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb1'
```

Что, в общем-то, чушь. Должно быть:

```
>>> u'апб'
u'\u0430\u043f\u0431'
```

Но и в этом случае получится `KeyError: u'\u0430'`.

Причина — `urllib.quote()` не понимает `unicode`, только `str`. Согласно RFC 3986, нужно перекодировать в UTF-8:

```
>>> urllib.quote(u'апб'.encode('utf-8'))
'%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B1'
```

Если нужна [нестандартная кодировка `%uXXXX`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations), то придется немного повыкручиваться в таком духе:

```
>>> urllib.quote(u'апб'.encode('unicode_escape')).replace('%5Cu', '%u')
'%u0430%u043f%u0431'
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.